# Как обычные комментарии WP заменить отзывами Woocommerce (с рейтингом)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как обычные комментарии WP заменить отзывами Woocommerce (с рейтингом)?

[Такую форму отзывов](http://35.170.225.58/?portfolio=alina) нужно заменить на такую как [здесь](http://35.170.225.58/?product=dobavit-anketu#comment-9). Как это сделать?

Comment: Я вам дал ссылку на то, как это делается, в вашем предыдущем вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/820614/220220.

Comment: Согласно правилам, Создайте минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Меня интересует на какие action вешать функции?

Comment: Код покажите, иначе разговарить не о чем. Никто не будет разбираться в вашем сайте снаружи. Согласно правилам, выдолжны привести код.